# Invalid username,password, security token

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, sandbox, salesforce-id

I am able to login to salesforce in live environment by using the url "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/33.0/0DFP0000000CamF".

But while trying in sandbox environment, I am getting an error like 'Invalid username,password, security token'. 
 Url used in sandbox environment is "https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/33.0/{organisational id}00D1100000BzHA7"

I think there is a problem with the organisational id given in the url.

Please suggest me how to resolve this.

Comment: Just asking, are you using the correct credentials for sandbox?

Comment: Yes the credentials are correct, As I am able to login to the site. I guess there is a problem in the url construction.

Comment: Have u tried 32 instead of 33?

Comment: I tried with 32 but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a stupid question, but did you make sure that it is in fact attempting to connect to `test.salesforce` instead of `login.salesforce`?

Comment: It is connecting to test.salesforce only

Answer (score 0):

I regenerated a new security token and it worked.